# issue with ModalPopup (ModalPopupExtender) with 2 updatepanels

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I have a ModalPopup with 2 updatepanels. It all works great, but I want the second update panel to show up only when the user picks an option in an asp:RadioButtonList in updatepanel 1.

When I set the Visible="false" on the second asp:UpdatePanel, the entire ModalPopup panel stops showing up. I only included part of the code, I have everything working as needed, but this is a nice to have... (Using VS2012 CSS3 HTML5 C#.NET on an ASP.NET Website)

Here is the aspx:

```
<div id="divScheduleTask" runat="server">

<asp:Panel ID="pnlScheduleTask" runat="server" >
     <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="udpScheduleTask">
         <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblTaskSch" Text="Task Scheduling: " runat="server" />
             <br />
             <asp:Label ID="lblSchType" runat="server" Text="Select Due Date Type :"/>
             <br />
             <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radSchType" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSchType_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem  Text="Exact DueDate" Value="Exact"/>
                <asp:ListItem  Text="Dynamic DueDate" Value="Dynamic"/>
             </asp:RadioButtonList><br />
         </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSch2" runat="server"  Visible="false">
          <ContentTemplate><asp:Label ID="lblDueDate" runat="server" Text="Select Due Date: " Visible="false"></asp:Label>
          </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel></div>
```

I tried to use a div, an asp:Table and now the 2nd updatePanel and as soon as I set the Visible="false" on any of these, the entire panel stops showing up.... What am I missing?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a control to visible prevents it from rendering. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.control.visible.aspx

What you can try is putting a div (runat server) or asp.net panel in the 2nd update panel and then when you need to hide it, try adding a style or css class to that div or panel which sets the style property of display to "none" like this:

```
.hiddenPanel{ display:none;}
```

The above code block is an example of a css class that you might define and which you would add to the div as a class reference such as class="hiddenPanel".

Comment: Thanks so much! and the other half of the equation - to show the div from within the C#, set <divName.Attributes["class"] = "classOfYourChoice";>.  I also had to add <AutoPostBack="true" to my radio button "radSchType" (see code above).

Comment: I had to make sure that there were no JS errors... If you use an update panel, you have to make sure that you have NO Javascript errors or the modal popup will be completely unpreditable. The JS Errors don't seem show up all the time in Chrome, but they seem to show in IE.

Comment: JS Errors can definitely prevent other functionality from executing. If you are using script that is not x-browser compatible, you should consider revising it or finding code that is.